# python how to split text into new list

Tags: python

Have numerous lines of text I would like to put into a list:

```
123456      123456      123456      234567      234567       4567890
243564      194563      432423      764575      542354       6564536
```

I think you get the idea.  Space separated values, each value should be it's own value.  73 values per line and something like 144 lines.  I know how to split based on the column:

```
d = list(zip(*(e.split() for e in b)))
```

How I split based on the row.  I want `d[0] = '123456,123456,123456,234567,234567,4567890'`

not `d[0] = '123456,243564'`

The above line splits the list up the way I don't want it split up.

EXTRA: Let me add one more thing in.

The data in the list are decimal numbers.  Is there a way when I go to separate out the list that is can also round the numbers.

```
f = np.round(float([e.split() for e in d]),2)
```

That only gives me the error 'float() argument must be a string or a number'

Comment: Thanks for the edit I goofed on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `zip()`; a list comprehension is enough here:

```
d = [e.split() for e in b]
```

If you need integers, you could use:

```
d = [[int(v) for v in e.split()] for e in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're insistent on the commas:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = [",".join(var.rstrip().split()) for var in f.readlines()]
    print(d[0])
    print(d[1])
```

Output:

```
123456,123456,123456,234567,234567,4567890
243564,194563,432423,764575,542354,6564536
```